# SSH Login success, Permission denied in remote machine

Tags: ssh, permissions, remote, key-authentication

I copied the ssh public key to a remote linux server with `ssh-copy-id`. ([Ref:  here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)) . And I am able to login with

```
local@Me$ ssh myuser@remote.ser.ver
login success
myuser@remote $ ll
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser ey 2048 Feb 21 14:23 MyStuffs/
drwx------ 2 myuser ey 2048 Feb 16 13:42 Rail/
myuser@remote $ cd Rail
Rail: Permission denied.
```

I checked the permission for `.ssh/authorized.keys` which is readable (obviously) and owned by `myuser`

```
myuser@remote $ ll .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser ey 793 Feb 22 10:02 authorized_keys
```

If instead I login with password  everything works

```
local@Me$ rm -rf .ssh
local@Me$ ssh myuser@remote.ser.ver
Enter password for myuser@remote.ser.ver : *****
login success
myuser@remote $ ll
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser ey 2048 Feb 21 14:23 MyStuffs/
drwx------ 2 myuser ey 2048 Feb 16 13:42 Rail/
myuser@remote $ cd Rail
myuser@remote $ pwd
/root/user/myuser/Rail
```

Comment: what happens when you login with your key and enter `id`

Comment: when logging with `ssh myuser@remote.ser.ver` it doesn't ask for anything. It simply logs in.

Comment: I mean, could you paste the output of the command `id` once you log in using your ssh key?

Comment: `id` on remote shell `myuser@remote $ id` gives `uid=15750(myuser) gid=1020(ey) groups=1020(ey),2208(xxx),1098827683`

Comment: what is the remote distribution? What shell do you have on the remote machine? Can you access the other directory? Can you go a level up?

Comment: I can level up. `/root/user/myuser/` directory in is `drwxr-xr-x` and owned by user `myuser`. The remote shell is `tcsh`. Again as I said, If I don't use ssh to login, and login with password, everything is normal.

Comment: Looks like you are logged-in in both cases. But some permission error. So I am wondering, are you logged-in as same user? Same shell? Same everything else?

Comment: only other thing I can think of is contents of `.ssh/authorized_keys` - is there anything else apart from the key signature? Is there anything non-default in `sshd_config`?

Comment: When you use `SSH` to login, are you able to `cd MyStuffs`?